# can I get help on DOB validation on magento

Tags: php, validation, magento

I am new in magento I would to validate my DOB fileds on the registratoin page so that valid dates can be inserted by the user, at the moment the input fieds accept anything and a user can input any number of text and it accepts can you guys please help?

Comment: You should probably use Zend_Validate_Date, have a look in the documentation

Answer (score 4):

Look in your theme's (or default) `template/customer/form/widget/dob.phtml` file. It creates three strings which describe the three text inputs for day, month and year. You can either add the `validate-number` name to their class or rewrite them to use `<select>` elements instead.

Comment: If you like an answer then [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) it by clicking the checkmark to it's left. :)